# Can you compress helium into a liquid and if so at what pressure will it liquify

Tags: thermodynamics, liquid-state

I want to know if helium will liquify under a certain pressure and exactly how much pressure would it take?

Comment: Don't post questions for which you are likely to find answers on the Google. You'll find enough details from the internet. See [Liquid helium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid_helium)

Comment: You missed out on Heike Kamerlingh Onnes' Nobel prize of 1913.

Comment: The question becomes meaningful if you specify the temperature.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a question asking for reference data which can be searched online.

Answer (score 1):

See the He phase diagram in my answer to [How much pressure will be generated if liquid helium is placed in a sealed container at room temperature?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/613105/how-much-pressure-will-be-generated-if-liquid-helium-is-placed-in-a-sealed-conta).  Below 5 K He can be two phase liquid/gas at certain pressures.  Below about 0.75 K it is all liquid.

Comment: Good answer. +1. You might want to add that above the critical temperature of 5.2 K no amount of pressure will liquefy helium.

Comment: @Dale Yes, thanks. My referenced earlier answer does address the critical point at about 5K.